# My conference paper is not published in IEEE Xplore because we didn't fill the copyright form in time

Tags: conference, copyright, ieee

We sent a paper to a conference and it was accepted.
We presented it and everything was fine.

Yesterday I accidentally see that the conference is indexed in IEEE Xplore, But our paper is not among the papers.

I emailed the conference and they said it is because we didn't reply to the IEEE email.
There wasn't any email from IEEE in my inbox, it was sent to my friend who was the first author. And he missed that email.

Now, what can we do? We filled the process today, Is there anything we could do to make our paper appear in IEEE Xplore?

Comment: With "friends" like that as co-authors, who needs inimical referees and editors :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first author should have been checking their email.

They may be able to publish it during the next cycle, you will have to discuss it with them but by not replying to their email you did not give them many options.

Comment: Yeah it was the first author fault but we did the process today. Is there anything we could do to publish our paper in IEEE Xplore? Can't day add it to the proceedings?

Comment: “You will have to discuss it with them”...